# How to prevent click event for one component from another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Please suggest how to Enable/Disable Toggle button from another component in ReactJS?

The idea is to Enable/Disable Toggle button from Statistics' `fetchStatistics()` function. When the logic of `fetchStatistics()` checks the response it should block Toggle button click or Enable click event for it.

1. **ProviderContainer** - root container

```
var ProviderContainer = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
            
    },

    render() {
            return (
                <div className="app">
                        <Provider />
                        <Provider />
                </div>
            );
        }    
});
```

2. **Provider** component

```
var Provider = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
            
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <li>
                 <Statistics />
                 <Toggle />
            </li>
        );
    }
});
```

3. **Statistics** component

```
var Statistics = React.createClass({
    fetchStatistics: function() {
        let url = "https://localhost/statistics";

        fetch(url)
        .then(data => {
            if (data) {
                // Disable click for <Toggle> button
            } else {
                // Enable click for <Toggle> button
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('error', error);
        });
    },

    render: function(){
        return(
            <div>
                ...
            </div>
        );
    }

});
```

4. **Toggle** component

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(e) {

    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="toogle active" onClick={this.handleClick} >
                <div className="toggle__manage"></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the code below. I have modified the `Provider`, `Statistics`, and `Toggle` components.

In the `Provider` component you'll need to manage a `allowToggle` state which is passed down to the `Toggle` component. The state can be changed via the `setAllowToggle` function which is passed down to the `Statistics` component.

```
var Provider = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {allowToggle: false};
    },


    setAllowToggle: function(allowToggle) {
        this.setState({ allowToggle });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <li>
                 <Statistics setAllowToggle={this.setAllowToggle}/>
                 <Toggle allowToggle={allowToggle}/>
            </li>
        );
    }
});
```

In the `Statistics` component the `setAllowToggle` and is called with `true` or `false` as per the condition.

```
var Statistics = React.createClass({
    fetchStatistics: function() {
        let url = "https://localhost/statistics";

        fetch(url)
        .then(data => {
            if (data) {
                // Disable click for <Toggle> button
                this.props.allowToggle(false);
            } else {
                // Enable click for <Toggle> button
                this.props.allowToggle(true);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('error', error);
        });
    },

    render: function(){
        return(
            <div>
                ...
            </div>
        );
    }

});
```

In the `Toggle` component the `allowToggle` prop is used to decide whether to allow toggle or not. Also, the `active` css class and the `onClick` function are conditionally provided.

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(e) {
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div 
                className={`toggle ${this.props.allowToggle ? 'active' : ''`}
                {...(this.props.allowToggle && {
                    onClick: this.handleClick
                })} 
            >
                <div className="toggle__manage"></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```